# How to implement getfacl in java (linux) since getacl() works only on windows

Tags: java, nfs, nfsclient

How to implement `getfacl()` in java (Linux) since `getacl()` works only on Windows. When I try to use `AclFileAttributeView` in Linux for nfsv4 mounted drive I get null pointer.

Comment: I think a good starting point would be to post your code, ideally in the form of an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Path file = Paths.get("<Path to the Mounted nfsv4 folder>"); AclFileAttributeView aclFileAttributeView = Files.getFileAttributeView(file, AclFileAttributeView.class);
System.out.println(aclFileAttributeView.getAcl());

Comment: @satishjohn This does not work on Linux, does it? Looking at the [source](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/da0da73ab82ed714dc5be94acd2f0d00fbdfe2e9/src/solaris/classes/sun/nio/fs/LinuxFileSystem.java#L66) of the Unix filesystem implementation, the list of provided views looks pretty static to me.

Comment: The `AclFileAttributeView` interface has been implemented on Windows and Solaris only, so this is going to be a hand-rolled implementation.